# Rectangle fits size automatically

Tags: reporting-services

I am using ssrs2008 ,I have created a rectangle and inside that I have create a table .In that table I have given some conditions to make it visible or hidden then according to those "table condition",
rectangle also changes its size (when table is visible rectangle is of different size and when it is invisible then rectangle also changes its size).I want to avoid that. so how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know its not possible to do that in SSRS.  Alternatively, though it would be a hack, you could make your table elements the same color as your background, thus appearing invisible and retaining your table shape.